# Repeat asking a series of numbers until the series is valid

Tags: java, loops, input

My goal is to ask the user a series of numbers, and it will only stop asking for more numbers once he reaches the maximum of 20 numbers or when he inputs a negative number. But I only want to use the series when the sum of the numbers is under 50 and there's no number superior than 15.

This is what I have written so far and I can't understand why it doesn't work

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class numbersSeries {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] numbers = new int[20];

        boolean invalid = true;
        int sum = 0, input = 0, counter = 0;

        while (invalid == true) {
            System.out.print("Series ");
            while ((input = in.nextInt()) > 0 && counter < 19) {
                numbers[counter] = input;
                sum += numbers[counter];
                boolean hasbignumber = false;  

                if(numbers[counter] > 15) {  
                    hasbignumber = true;  
                }
                if(sum < 50 && hasbignumber == false) {
                    invalid = false;
                }
                counter++;
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

EDIT!!
I forgot to mention something very important. Once the series is discarded the loop will start all over again, take this output for example

```
Series 1 2 4 30 -3                //this series will be discarded because the fourth value surpasses the maximum of 20
Series 4 9 8 8 3 8 6 1 15 15 -2   //this one too because the sum is over 50 
Series 3 1 9 0 -2                 //only this one is going to be used because it fits all conditions
```

So all I want is for the compiler to keep asking for new series until a valid one is introduced so I can use it posteriorly.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Now you’re in here, you should learn how to ask questions the smart way for great chances of helpful answers. First, in what was doesn’t your program work?? What is the specific difference between desired and observed behaviour? “Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.”

Comment: To input 20 numbers I think you need either `counter < 20` or `counter <= 19`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use an embedded `while` here since it is not needed.

> it will only stop asking for more numbers once he reaches the maximum
>   of 20 numbers or when he inputs a negative number

`while ((input = in.nextInt()) > 0 && counter < 19)`  condition means the loop
exits if `0` or less value is submitted as input or the variable `counter`  reaches 19.
`0` is not a negative value as you wish and the maximum number of `20` cannot be reached with this condition.

The `boolean` variable name is misleading :

```
 while (invalid == true) {
```

give the feeling that we expect to have a valid input to exit while it is not your need.

You should use a `boolean` variable name which conveys your rule :

For example for this rule :

> I only want to use the series when the sum of the numbers is under 50
>   and there's no number superior than 15.

Your could use the `boolean` variable `mustKeepSerie`.
And to exit the loop you could put the `boolean` expression in the `while` condition.

At the beginning,`mustKeepSerie` is set to `true` as no violation of the rule is possible as the input has not started yet. 
If at any time, the sum of the numbers is superior to 50 and there's at least a number superior to 15, `mustKeepSerie` is set to `false` but the loop is not impacted as you asked.

And in the while, we have a single condition to loop :

```
while ((input = in.nextInt()) >= 0 && counter < 20 )
```

which corresponds to :

> it will only stop asking for more numbers once he reaches the maximum
>   of 20 numbers or when he inputs a negative number.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] numbers = new int[20];

    boolean mustKeepSerie = true;
    int sum = 0, input = 0, counter = 0;

    System.out.print("Series ");
    while ((input = in.nextInt()) >= 0 && counter < 20) {
        numbers[counter] = input;
        sum += numbers[counter];

        // mustKeepSerie condition
        boolean hasbignumber = false;
        if (numbers[counter] > 15) {
          hasbignumber = true;
        }
        if (sum > 50 || hasbignumber) {
          mustKeepSerie = false;
        }
        counter++;
    }

    if (mustKeepSerie) {
       // do your processing     
    }

   }
```

---

**Edit new solution after comment**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  int[] numbers = new int[20];

  // boolean mustKeepSerie = true;
  int sum = 0, input = 0, counter = 0;

  System.out.print("Series ");

  boolean isAcceptableSerie = false;

  boolean isCurrentSerieValid = true;

  while (!isAcceptableSerie) {

    input = in.nextInt();

    // condition exit or loop again if input <0
    if (input < 0) {

      if (isCurrentSerieValid) {
         isAcceptableSerie = true;
       }

       else {
         printDiscardedSerie(numbers,counter);
         sum = 0;
         counter = 0;
         isCurrentSerieValid=true;
       }
       continue;
    }

    numbers[counter] = input;
    sum += numbers[counter];

    if (sum > 50 || numbers[counter] > 15) {
      isCurrentSerieValid = false;
    }

    // condition exit or loop again if counter==19
    if (counter == 19) {
      if (isCurrentSerieValid) {
          isAcceptableSerie = true;
      }
      else {
          printDiscardedSerie(numbers,counter);
          sum = 0;
          counter = 0;
          isCurrentSerieValid=true;
      }
      continue;
    }
    counter++;
  }
}


private static void printDiscardedSerie(int[] numbers, int counter) {
  System.out.print("Series ");
  for (int i=0; i<counter;i++){
    if (i>=1){
      System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print(numbers[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! but I haven't explained myself correctly so I edited the question, if you could take a look at it, sorry and thank you :)

Comment: That's really good, thank you! It just lacks the simple feature of showing the String "Series " after every discarded series, any way to implement that?

Comment: you are welcome :) just create a private method which takes as parameter a `int array` (`int[]`) and iterate on the array to print each values.

Comment: I haven't learned that yet :/ is it possible to make without methods?

Comment: I will edit the code to show that because doing all in the same method makes the mode not readable. Just done.

Comment: Alright! Thank you for your help and availability :)

Answer (score 0):

```
I strongly recommend you to use function/methods whatever you call it for all this, that will help you visualize the code a lot better.


import java.util.Scanner;

class numbersSeries 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     int[] numbers = new int[20];

     //boolean invalid = true; // not needed
     int sum = 0, input = 0, counter = 0;

     String finalMSG = ""; // just visual console details.

     while(true)
     {
        if(counter >= 20)
         {
            finalMSG = "Serie is not Valid!";
            break;
         }

        System.out.print("Enter number #" + (counter + 1) + ": ");
        input = in.nextInt();   

        if(input < 0)
        {
            counter = 0;
            sum = 0;
            numbers = new int[20];
            finalMSG = "Serie is not Valid!";
            break;
        } // if negative            

        numbers[counter] = input;
        counter++;          
      }//while 


      for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
      {
         if(numbers[i] > 15)
         {
            finalMSG = "Serie is not Valid! There's a number > 15.";
            break;
         }

         else if(sum >= 50)
         {
            finalMSG = "Serie is not Valid!";
            break;
         }  

         else
         {
            finalMSG = "Serie is Valid!";
            sum+= numbers[i];
         }
      }//for

      System.out.println(finalMSG + " sum is: " + sum);
      System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! First I dont want to use methods on this one, and second I didnt explain myself right on the question, so i edited it, but basically I want the compiler to keep asking for new series until a valid one is introduced, and on every cycle it shows the string "Series ". I'm sorry for not explainind myself correctly, I'm still a begginer in here.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the conditions into the while loop, rather than trying to do the logic inside the while loop itself.

```
input = in.nextInt();
while(input<15 && counter < 19 && sum < 50) {
  numbers[counter]=input;
  sum+=numbers[counter];
  counter++;
  input = in.nextInt();
}
```